# Return value only

Tags: java, return-value

I want to print the mean and the median calculated from an array of integers. Here is my code:

```
// I create and populate the int array
public static int[] populateArray(Scanner input) {
    int[] array = new int[input.nextInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    return array;
}

// I create a method wich takes as formal paramether an array of int an prints the result of mean from the array

public static void printMean(int[] populatedArray) {
    double mean = 0;
    for (int aPopulatedArray : populatedArray) {
        mean += aPopulatedArray;
    }
    mean /= populatedArray.length;
    System.out.println(mean);
}

// I create a method wich takes as formal paramether an array of int an prints the result of median from the array

public static void printMedian(int[] populatedArray) {
    Arrays.sort(populatedArray);
    double median;
    if (populatedArray.length % 2 != 0) {
        median = populatedArray[populatedArray.length / 2];
    } else {
        median = (populatedArray[populatedArray.length / 2] + populatedArray[populatedArray.length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
    }
    System.out.println(median);
}
```

In Main, I first want to call the `populateArray()` method.I will populate my array. Then, how can I pass as a formal parameter, to the other 2 methods(`printMean()` and `printMedian()`) only the array from `populateArray()`?

I don't want to do this, each time I use the array from `populateArray()` method:

```
int[] array = new int[input.nextInt()];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

I want to populate an array an then use those values in both print methods.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood now!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much of an issue with the structure of your code, assuming the logic is right.  Just obtain your populated array, and then use it in the other two methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = populateArray(new Scanner(System.in));
    printMean(array);
    printMedian(array);
}
```

You should get away with this because your helper methods read, but do not modify, the input array.  This means that you can just keep passing your initial array to the subsequent method.

Comment: That's not quite correct. `printMedian` does modify the array; it sorts it. But that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

You main method should be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = populateArray(new Scanner(System.in)); //Get a populated array
    printMean(arr); //Pass it to printMean
    printMedian(arr); //Pass it to PrintMedian
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually

> Arrays.sort(populatedArray)

does modify the populatedArray. It has no effect on your posted code, because the mean calculation doesn't care about the order of the array's values.
But if you plan further developping, I would suggest e.g. copying to not manipulate the original populatedArray:

```
public static void printMedian(int[] populatedArray) {
    int[] copiedArray = new int[populatedArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(populatedArray, 0, copiedArray, 0, populatedArray.length);
    Arrays.sort(copiedArray);
    double median;
    if (copiedArray.length % 2 != 0) {
        median = copiedArray[copiedArray.length / 2];
    } else {
        median = (copiedArray[copiedArray.length / 2] + copiedArray[copiedArray.length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
    }
    System.out.println(median);
}
```

And then you can apply the main methods from the posts above without manipulating the populatedArray.